# org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.value.StringValue; local class incompatible

Tags: java, jackrabbit

my code is

```
Repository repository = new URLRemoteRepository("http://localhost:8088/rmi");
    //  Repository repository = JcrUtils.getRepository();
    Session session = repository.login(new SimpleCredentials("admin", "admin".toCharArray()));
        Node root = session.getRootNode(); 
        System.out.println("get root node..");
        // Store content 
        Node hello = root.addNode("hello55555555555"); 
        Node world = hello.addNode("world"); 
        world.setProperty("message", "Hello, World!"); 
        session.save(); 
        System.out.println("repository accessed successfully......");
```

i am getting following error

```
get root node..
org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.client.RemoteRepositoryException:
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is:
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.jackrabbit.rmi.value.StringValue; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -6456025645604163205, local class serialVersionUID = 220963478492833703
```

Comment: Needs more information. Software versions.... And what exactly is serving that URI?

Answer (score 1):

The message is self-explanatory. You have different versions of the software at server and client, and the Jackrabbit people haven't done the right thing with their `serialVersionUIDs`.